# Apple photos takes seconds to load in file chooser dialog

Tags: photos, filesystem, performance, photos.app

See image below. The spinner takes almost 10 seconds before showing actual photos. I'm on a 2014 MBP with SSD and I have only around 16.000 photos (60GB in total). This slow loading time only occurs in the file chooser, not in the actual Apple Photos application. It has been like this since I remember, but I'm starting to doubt if this is normal.

So, are there people who don't think this is normal and have an idea of how it can be fixed?

[image]